# Why equals() is not invoked with @IdClass

Tags: jpa, annotations, persistence, equals, composite-primary-key

I want to use @IdClass annotation to make a composite PK of Long and Date values. When debugging I've noticed that the equals() method is not invoked, my breakpoint never hits.

Here is the code snippet:

Entity class

```
@Entity

@Table(name = "view_ins_test", schema = "dbo")

@IdClass(value = InsPK.class)

public class InsTest {

@Id

@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

@Column(name = "ins_id", nullable = false)

private Long id;



@Id

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)

@Column(name = "ins_data")

private Date data;



// + getters/setters

}
```

Composite PK class:

```
public class InsPK implements Serializable {



private Long id;

private Date data;



public InsPK() {

}



public InsPK(Long id, Date data) {

this.id = id;

this.data = data;

}



@Override

public int hashCode() {

int hash = 7;

hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.id);

hash = 89 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.data);

return hash;

}



@Override

public boolean equals(Object obj) {

if (this == obj) return true;

if (!(obj instanceof InsPK)) return false;

InsPK other = (InsPK) obj;

return Objects.equals(this.id, other.id) && Objects.equals(this.data, other.data);

}



// + getters/setters

}
```

I have tried several variations but did not manage to make it work. What could be the problem in such case and what is the best way to solve it?